# Nested Observables from API Angular2

Tags: angular, observable

I need to make multiple calls to a few endpoints in my resolver function. All the following functions return an observable.

```
return getAllAccounts().flatMap(data => {
  return Observable.forkJoin(getAllLevelData(data), getAllFundingData(data))
})
```

I was able to get the data to return back properly for the `getAllLevelData(data)` function, as it is not as nested as the second observable in the `forkJoin`.

```
let getAllLevelData = function(data) {
  return Observable.forkJoin(
    data.map(i => {
      return anotherObservable(i.clientId)
    })
  )
}
```

However, for the second observable, it's a lot more nested and I'm not able to get the data returned back properly. Is there a better way I can be handling this?

```
let getAllFundingData = function(data){
  return Observable.forkJoin(
    data.map(i => {
      return fundingFn(i.id)
        .flatMap(pArray => {
          pArray.map(j => {
            return Observable.forkJoin(Observable.of(j.cost), thirdObservable(j.id))
          })
        })
    })
  )
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any error? or simply just getting nothing for the second element?

Comment: Not getting any error, but when I try to reference the data from the resolver in the component, I'll get an array of observables returned rather than the actual values. I am just wondering if there is an better way to do this!